# Visual Studio 2017 project reference support between .net standard and .net core

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, .net-standard, codelens, live-unit-tests

I have a .Net standard 2.0 project in a Visual Studio solution that contains some Azure functions.  In the same solution, I've created a .Net Core 2.0 Unit Test project.  I've added a project reference from the .Net Core Unit Test project to the .Net standard 2.0 library.

Despite the project reference, Visual Studio is behaving like I'm referencing a dll instead of the project.  For example, if I try to use F12/Go to reference, it brings me to a 'From metadata' file instead of the actual code file in the other project.  Additionally, codelens features like 'Tested by' (and even just 'referenced by') and the Live Unit testing icons in the .Net Standard project aren't working, since they don't seem to be aware of the Unit Test project at all.

Is there some way to get this integration working between the two projects?  My Visual Studio is up to date (15.5.3 enterprise), and I'm not using any tools like Resharper or anything like that.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing the same issue but so far the project reference vs dll reference is not the case. I believe this is an existing issue with Azure function projects. There is a [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/483946/f12-does-not-work-in-azure-function-based-project.html) in Microsoft community regarding this issue. The last comment from Visual Studio is as follows:

> I'm closing this report, because in the last 90 days there was no internal developer activity and very small number of new votes or comments. Sorry, we would like to look at this further, but we just don’t have the time right now. Our goal in closing older issues such as this one is to keep customers informed on which issues are currently being pursued by Visual Studio teams. If you still have trouble with our latest version, please report it as a new problem.